# Integrate gmail in android app just like facebook integration

Tags: android, gmail

I want to integrate gmail authentication with my android app just like facebook authentication(by giving username and password).

I have gone through https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in the site and I don't want to integrate google plus(because I'm using an emulator which has no google plus installed application). Also I don't want to authenticating using my existing account in my device.

I have seen lots of similar questions here and most of them are redirected to goole+ or use account manager to access existing account. I need a good tutorial which contains all the procedures to be carried out. I hope you understand  what I meant. Please help..

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644337/can-i-use-accountmanager-to-let-users-sign-in-with-their-google-account
it uses AccountManager, but I think that allows you to login with a google account.

Comment: Go to this link: [Google Account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644337/can-i-use-accountmanager-to-let-users-sign-in-with-their-google-account?lq=1)